# Botones en vertical JOptionPane

Tags: java, poo, netbeans, class, joptionpane

En el siguiente código, ¿se pueden poner los botones del JOptionPane.showOptionDialog en vertical? En caso de que si que se pueda, ¿cómo se haría?

Muchas gracias.

```
public class Principal {                            // Clase Principal donde se ejecutará la aplicación.

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    
    String opciones[] = {"Nuevo Vehículo", "Listar Vehículos", "Buscar Vehículo", "Modificar kms Vehículo", "Salir"};
    int eleccion = 0;
    
    do {
        eleccion = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Seleccione una opción", "Concesionario Pozo's Cars", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, opciones, 0);
        
    } while (eleccion != 4);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Solo el contenido del JoptioPane puede ir en vertical, las opciones o botones por defecto se colocan de forma horizontal.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html

Por lo que un truco seria crear tus propios botones y agregarlos en un arreglo de objetos. Para que luego, el arreglo pase a ser el contenido del JoptionePane, de esa manera se mostraran en forma vertical. ahora solo te quedaría hacer uso de esos botones.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main {
//Metodo para hacer uso de los botones creados
//Se usa substring para obtener la primera letra de cada opcion y mediante un switch hacer uso de la opcion correspondiente.
    public static JButton getButton(String text) {
        final JButton button = new JButton(text);
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                String opcion=actionEvent.getActionCommand ().substring (0,1);
                switch (opcion) {
                    case "N" -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Nuevo vehiculo");
                    case "L" -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Listar Vehiculos");
                    case "B" -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Buscar vehiculos");
                    case "M" -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null,"Modificar kms de un vehiculo");
                }
            }
        };
        button.addActionListener(actionListener);
        return button;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Icon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\car.png");
        JButton a = getButton ("Nuevo vehiculo");
        JButton b = getButton ("Listar Vehiculo");
        JButton c = getButton ("Buscar Vehiculo");
        JButton d = getButton ("Modificar Kms Vehiculo");
        //arreglo de botones tipo Object
        Object []opciones={a,b,c,d};

          JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, opciones, "Concesionario Pozo's Cars",
                JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,icon,
                new String[]{"Salir"},
                null);


    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No se como darte las gracias por la explicación. Eres un fenómeno. Muchísimas gracias!!!